# How to get a control custom resource data

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, resources

You can get common controls custom resource data ( see controlData section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380902(v=VS.85).aspx ) by handling WM_CREATE and accesing lpCreateParams member of CREATESTRUCT. Is there any way to access the data after a control was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer. We can use FindResource->LoadResource->LockResource functions to get pointer to the dialog resource data. The pointer returned by LockResource will point to DLGTEMPLATEEX structure. This will allow to iterate through dialog controls to find the needed dialog item ( DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX ) and extract custom resource data from it

Comment: I missed where the control (and thus the additional parameters) was defined in a dialog resource.   I was assuming you were asking for any general window/control created by CreateWindow().

Comment: I can't find a definition of `DLGTEMPLATEEX `.

Answer (score -1):

lpCreateParams is just a *pointer* to the additional creation parameters, as supplied by the caller.   Its not the data itself.

The creator of the window/control would not make any guarantees to keep that data around after creation.

So, no.

Comment: the properties of the control are not invalidated pointer or not. They are accessible for as long as the control exists.